# ffmpeg - capturing RTP stream to video file and ffplay simultaneously

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rtp

I want to capture an RTP stream to a video file, and monitor it at the same time.

Given a .sdp file, I can capture the stream with:

`ffmpeg -y -protocol_whitelist file,rtp,udp -i video.sdp -an -c:v copy out.mp4`

And I can play the live stream with:

`ffplay -protocol_whitelist file,rtp,udp -i video.sdp`

But I want to do the same thing simultaneously.

I can't run both processes at the same time because I can't bind the two processes to the same port. I've also tried using [`tee`](https://superuser.com/questions/343586/how-to-display-and-capture-webcam-stream-at-the-same-time), but I've run into issues where the muxer doesn't support non-seekable output (I suspect because I'm outputting to .mp4).

How can I record and playback at the same time?

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved with the [TVideoGrabber SDK](https://www.datastead.com/products/video-sdk/) and RTSP/RTMP/HTTP/ONVIF Source filter.

Put a TVideoGrabber component on the form, the live stream will be displayed in the control:

```
videoGrabber.VideoSource = vs_IPCamera;<br/>
videoGrabber.SetAuthentication (at_IPCamera, "user", "password");<br/>
videoGrabber.IPCameraURL = "rtsp://...";<br/>
videoGrabber.FrameGrabber = fg_Disabled;<br/>
videoGrabber.RecordingMethod = rm_MP4;<br/>
videoGrabber.RecordingFileName = "output.mp4";<br/>
videoGrabber.StartRecording();
```